# Why promise reject does not handle an error

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm using nodejs `request` package (2.88 version) with node v10.24.1

The Promise below does not handle an error if the url simply was not specified. I'm getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and from the `request package` source I can see an exception thrown for that case.
If I remove the `async` keyword everything works fine, and the reject handled.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   request(uri: url).on('error', err => {
      reject();
   }).on('response', response => {
      resolve();
   });
});
```

Could you please explain what happens. Probably the request's exception finished before the reject actually fired. Any details please.

Comment: The function you're passing to `new Promise()` should _never_ be async, but if it is.. I don't see why this would fail. The behavior should be similar.

Comment: So maybe you can share a more complete example that demonstrates error handling not working. But just to repeat, if this is just an academic exercise then cool! But _don't use async_ here.

Comment: @Evert, outer function is async. Everything on `error` handles fine, but if there is no url specified it fails. If I simply add try/catch inside promise it works fine as well, but I realize it's wrong and shouldn't be that.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense! I'll answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function to `new Promise`, this function gets *immediately* executed.

There's no magic here, for the purpose of illustration, the constructor of `new Promise()` might look a bit like this:

```
class Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    executor(this.resolveFunction, this.rejectFunction); 
  }
}
```

So this example:

```js
new Promise(() => {
  console.log(1);
});
console.log(2);
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
```

This is important, because if you pass something to `new Promise` that throws an exception, this happens immediately too:

```
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  throw new Error('foo');
});
```

The error thrown here doesn't cause the promise to be rejected, it completely prevents `new Promise()` from succeeding. No promise is returned, and the exception is thrown in the *outer* function that called `new Promise()`.

However, this breaks down when you pass an async function:

```js
new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
  throw new Error('foo');
});
```

Because of how async functions work, this error will *not* be thrown during the setup of `new Promise()`, but the async function you passed will handle the error asyncronously and returns a rejected promise, that `new Promise()` doesn't know how to handle.

This is no different from calling an async function directly yourself and not handling errors:

```js
(async () => {
  throw new Error('foo');
})();
```

So the reason things are failing have less to do with `new Promise()`, but more with the fact how async functions work in general.

Just a last time for future readers, you should never pass an `async` executor to `new Promise()`, because:

- The only reason you need `async` at all is so you can use `await`.
- `await` only works with promises.
- If you *already* had a promise you wanted to `await`, you didn't need `new Promise()` to begin with, because the main use-case of `new Promise` is to convert something that *doesnt* use promises into something that does.